# Missing DLLImport even though there is a "using InteropServices"

Tags: c#, dll

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MapsApp.DB;

namespace MapsApp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [DLLImport("GeoUrbanApp.exe")]
        public static extern double CalcFigure(double east, double north, double size);
...
```

I am trying to call the CalcFigure function from the .exe. I've added it in the references, and trying to import it. All I get is:

```
The type or namespace name 'DLLImport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'DLLImportAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The solution most people find online is the "using System.Runtime.InteropServices;" but I have it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's `DllImport` not `DLLImport`

:)

Comment: Heh, thanks, you are correct! I took it from one of the answers on stackoverflow, apparently this person was not cautious in what he wrote.

Answer (score 91):

Try adding

`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

to your class, that's the namespace the `DllImportAttribute` resides in.